# How can I create graphql objects on the backend?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

If I have `var obj = { name: 'Bill', ... etc}` and a GraphQLObjectType like `const Person = new GraphQLObjectType({name: 'person', fields: { ...some fields with graphql types ... }});`

How do I get a hydrated GraphQL object like the ones that are returned from the server: `{ name 'Bill', age: null, __typename: 'Person' }`

Note: I need to get this object and use it on the server.

Comment: to be clear, are you asking about how to take a POJO, add a schema and get a validated GraphQL return type (the type that a query or mutation will return to the frontend)?  But by doing it outside of a resolve method?

Comment: @thataustin yes, that is what I need to do

Comment: You can you graphql-tools: https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tools